# Android - Intercept Link From Webview

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-intent, webview

So I need the user clicked link in webview, in this case it is a link containing a .pdf file.  I have code that launches the PDF reader but it doesn't get the link so it just loads the PDF reader on click of a PDF file.  How do I intercept this link and feed it to my PDF reader intent?

Code:

```
public class atcFaa extends Activity {
WebView webview;
private String url;
ProgressBar pd = null;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.atccti);

    pd = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.web_view_progress_bar);

    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.ctiWebView);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    Button openPdfBtn = new Button(this);
    webview.addJavascriptInterface(openPdfBtn, "openPdfBtn");
    openPdfBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            openPdf();
        }
    });

    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            if (progress < 100 && pd.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE) {
                pd.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
            }
            pd.setProgress(progress);
            if (progress == 100) {
                pd.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
            }
        }
    });

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            // do your handling codes here, which url is the requested url
            // probably you need to open that url rather than redirect:
            if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url)));
            } else if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
                url = url.replaceFirst("mailto:", "");
                url = url.trim();
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("plain/text").putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                        new String[] { url });
                startActivity(i);

            } else if (url.startsWith("geo:")) {
                try {
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }

            } else if (url.endsWith("pdf")) {
                try {

                }

                catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(atcFaa.this, "No PDF Viewer Installed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            else {
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }
            return true;
            // then it is not handled by default action
        }

    });

    webview.loadUrl("http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/");
}

protected void openPdf() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu2, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.atcAbout2:
        Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the icon!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        break;
    case R.id.atcContact2:
        emailme();
        break;

    }
    return true;
}

private void emailme() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String domsEmail = "MYEMAIL@EXAMPLE.com";
    String message = "Insert Message Here";
    String myemail[] = { domsEmail };
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, myemail);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
            "ATC Assistant");
    emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
    startActivity(emailIntent);
}

/*
 * @Override public void onBackPressed() { if (webview.canGoBack())
 * webview.goBack(); else super.onBackPressed(); }
 */

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}
}
```

Comment: You're already overriding the link loading - you should just have to call you openPdf() function in the "endswith(pdf)" case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the structure of your html code, but I'll pretend you have a button. Here the code to have in your html:

```
<button onclick='openPdfBtn.performClick();'>Open pdf</button>
```

and then add a js interface to your webview:

```
Button openPdfBtn = new Button(this); //this is not gonna be visible
yourWebView.addJavascriptInterface(openPdfBtn, "openPdfBtn"); //here you bind the js with the native button
openPdfBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        openPdf();
    }
});
```

Comment: I have no button, it is a pure webview.  I want the app to recognize that a link to a PDF file is clicked and either launch a way to view it or load it into google docs to view it.

Comment: What do you mean it is a pure webview? You have no control on the html? You open generic html pages?

Comment: I specify the link yes, but it is just a view of the page.  On the page there are PDF file links that I would like viewed.  I will edit the original post with the complete code.

Comment: Well, it is the same, just specify the onclik on the href

Comment: The native button is needed just for the binding with js interface, it is not visible at all, it is not in your layout.

Comment: I don't really understand how I am supposed to add this, I attempted to modify the code but I had errors.

Comment: So your html link (href) has to have the onclick. Then Just paste the java code in your onCreate method. The method addJavascriptInterface binds the native android widget (Button) to the js interface through the string used on the onclick...

Comment: Thank you, I edited my post to show the code inserted, although when a PDF is clicked nothing happens. The top line you say to put in my HTML, I cannot do anything with this.  I do not own the website and not sure what to do with that.  Am I on the right track here?

Comment: That's the problem, you need to match the "openPdfBtn" with onclick='openPdfBtn.performClick();' in the html. Could I see the source html code just for the link?